# LLVM IR for Swift Function + dependencies

Tags: swift, llvm, llvm-ir

I have a function (written in Swift) and I would like to get the LLVM IR for the function PLUS any dependencies so that I can run the resulting LLVM IR in a fully self-contained environment.

As an example, consider the following function:

```
func plus(a: Int, b: Int) ->Int {
    return a + b
}

plus(5, 7)
```

I can pass the `emit-ir` option to `swiftc`, however, the resulting LLVM IR contains external calls and the resulting IR cannot be run using `lli` (the error is shown below).

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '__TFSsa6C_ARGVGVSs20UnsafeMutablePointerGS_VSs4Int8__' which could not be resolved!
```

Is there any way of grabbing the IR for these external functions so that I can use `lli` to run the program?